# TYPO3 8.7.24: graphical bug when using selectTree in tca

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript, extbase, typo3-8.x

[image: svg icon][image: Graphical/SVG Bug in selectTree]

When I'm using rendermode selectTree for my kategorie selection, then I've got an graphical bug. The bug independent from browser (tested in chrome and firefox). I found out, that it looks like the svg icon I'm using for this type.

My tca config for the field "eltern":

```
    'eltern' => [
        'exclude' => true,
        'label' => 'Eltern',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'select',
            'renderType' => 'selectTree',
            'foreign_table' => 'tx_adressen_domain_model_adresskategorie',
            'foreign_table_where' => 'ORDER BY tx_adressen_domain_model_adresskategorie.kategoriename',
            'size' => 20,
            'treeConfig' => [
                'parentField' => 'eltern',
                'appearance' => [
                    'expandAll' => true,
                    'showHeader' => true,
                ],
            ],
            'maxitems' => 1,
            'minitems' => 0,
        ],
    ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved the problem with using a 16x16 Pixel PNG icon instead of a svg icon

TCA:

```
return [
...
  'iconfile' => 'EXT:adressen/Resources/Public/Icons/Adresskategorie.png',
...
```

Comment: This is actually a known bug. The SVG itself needs a width and height attribute.

Comment: Could you please mark your questions as answered, because that would help other people to either find it as ananswered question that resolves their problem, or it would help people like me, who try to answer unanswered questions, since they could filter that question via stack overflow's tags.